# optimize query: get all votes from user's item

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

i did it my way because i'm very bad getting results from two tables...

Basically, first i get all the id items that correspond to the user, and then i calculate the ratings of each item.

But, there is two different types of object item, so i do this 2 times: show you:

```
    function votos_usuario($id){

//            $previa = "SELECT id FROM preguntas WHERE id_usuario = '$id'";
//            $r_previo = mysql_query($previa);
//            $ids_p = '0, ';
//            while($items_previos = mysql_fetch_array($r_previo)){
//                $ids_p .= $items_previos['id'].", ";
//                //echo "ids pregunta usuario: ".$items_previos['id']."<br>";
//            }
//            $ids = substr($ids_p,0,-2);
//            //echo $ids;
//
//            $consulta = "SELECT valor FROM votos_pregunta WHERE id_pregunta IN ( $ids )";
//            //echo $consulta;
//
//           $resultado = mysql_query($consulta);
//           $votos_preguntas = 0;
//           while($voto = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
//             $votos_preguntas = $votos_preguntas + $voto['valor'];
//           }
$votos_preguntas= 0;
$votos_preguntas = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM votos_pregunta WHERE id_pregunta IN (SELECT id FROM preguntas WHERE id_usuario = '$id')");



           $previa_r = "SELECT id FROM recetas WHERE id_usuario = '$id'";
            $r_previo_r = mysql_query($previa_r);
            $ids_r = '0, ';
            while($items_previos_r = mysql_fetch_array($r_previo_r)){
                $ids_r .= $items_previos_r['id'].", ";
                //echo "ids pregunta usuario: ".$items_previos['id']."<br>";
            }
            $ids = substr($ids_r,0,-2);
            $consulta_b = "SELECT valor FROM votos_receta WHERE id_receta IN ( $ids )";
            //echo $consulta;

           $resultado_b = mysql_query($consulta_b);
           $votos_recetas = 0;
           while($voto_r = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_b)){
             $votos_recetas = $votos_recetas + $voto_r['valor'];
           }





            $total = $votos_preguntas + $votos_recetas;
            return $total;

        }
```

As you can si this is two much.. O(n^2)

Feel like thinking?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for both:

```
$votos_preguntas = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM votos_pregunta WHERE id_pregunta IN (SELECT id FROM preguntas WHERE id_usuario = '$id')");
```

If `votos_pregunta` and `votos_rectas` have the same structure, I would only have it as one table with a newly added `type` column that could be either rectas or preguntas.  Then you need to only do one statement for `$total`.

Comment: wow! didn't know you could do that!!! ok, i'll update the code and edit my question :) thanks!

Comment: it doesn't return the same value... you can check diference at recetorium.com (previous) recetorium.com/pruebas (your code)

Comment: edited it, thanks! by the way. keep them in different tables because thought i'd be better whem there are many many votes on database.. no?

Comment: what is different on those two sites? they look like they return the same things to me

Comment: no, no, if you look to the number next to each username, its like in bright brown color... basically it gives massive results :S

Comment: ok, you right. i updated the server before i went to bed.. but for example, to me, toni user, shows 50 votes when i have only 4 :S